# Cleaning silicone molds

Tags: everyday-chemistry

I am a musician who wears custom-molded in-ear monitors made of silicone. They are rather expensive so I need to constantly clean them and carefully. I was told not to use isopropyl alcohol (96%) wipes because it will eat away at the silicone. I looked this up and somebody said it has to do with the molecular weight. Is it true that it would damage the silicone, or just make it bloat for a while until the alcohols are evaporated? What about carbamide peroxide, which is sold as an earwax remover?

Comment: Peroxide compounds might be too reactive to trust with polymers like silicone - just a general rule of thumb guess, I don't know specifically.

Comment: If the silicone swells in isoprop, it is in grave danger. Squeeze a jelly bear you put in water for an hour and you know what I mean. Otherwise, you only put them in your own ears, right? Wipe clean with a dry cloth, or use liquid soap / your shower gel if necessary. I would never use funny chemicals here.

Comment: Soap/water is your best bet. Do the IEM's have a silicone head that you can detatch and wash separately? Or are the drivers just embedded in the silicone. Asking because if you dunk it in water, you might damage the drivers.